# IP Block and Integrated Circuit using Image Compression and Parameters

Tags: image-processing

I have to research and compare IP cores for FPGA and ICs that use image compression algorithms.

1.) I couldn't find any IP Cores apart from a few IP Cores(JPEG IP Core KJN Series). At the same time, I did not come across any ICs. Can you give a few examples or where should I start researching them?

2.) What should the comparison parameters be? I found FPS, data rates, bit depth, power consumption, entry bit resolution parameters. But what more parameters can I add to this comparison? Or should I find them by looking at the datasheet?

Comment: I doubt it would be relevant to create image compression IC. These days more and more things are integrated in SoCs (system-on-chip). So either your implement an IP in a FPGA coprocessor, use an integrated IP in a Microprocessor-based SoC or try a purely software solution (not always realistic) with an off-the-shelf library

Comment: Latency can be a killer for some applications. That's why some people use Motion JPEG instead of more advanced Video codecs.

Answer (score -1):

> I couldn't find any IP Cores apart from a few IP Cores(JPEG IP Core KJN Series). At the same time, I did not come across any ICs. Can you give a few examples or where should I start researching them?

There are quite a few off the shelf processors with image processing capabilities. The most popular options these days are probably ARM cores which chips made by TI, NXP, ST, etc.

> What should the comparison parameters be

That depends heavily on the requirements of your specific application: cost, size, power consumption, I/O, libraries, Real time OS, pin count and configuration, performance CPU/GPU, memory, peripherals, etc.. Generally you start with the detailed list of requirements and then plow through the data sheets of each processor to find the best fit.

Comment: You are right! We have different options for thinking in terms of microprocessors. However I research just IC because I'm trying to make a compression between ICs and IP cores. If we think in terms of processors, can you give an example of this comparison?

Comment: Any comparison needs to be based on the specific requirements of your requirements. It's like comparing cars: a sports car is different from a mini van is different from heavy truck. None is inherently better, it's just about choosing the best for the  job at hand.